# How should I setup a spaCy server to handle multiple concurrent requests(non-blocking)?

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading, multiprocessing, ubuntu-18.04, spacy

I'm having a script that contains a few data preprocessing functions using spaCy. I need to execute the script as a REST API server but the problem is I don't have batches of texts so I can't easily use spaCy's "nlp.pipe()" function.

I can execute the script as a flask REST API server using gunicorn with multi-threading but I need to know if there's another much better feasible way to handle thousands of concurrent requests in this case.

This is just a demo script but the actual script contains similar functions:

```
import string
import spacy

nlp = spacy.load('en')

d = string.punctuation
d = "".join(d.translate(str.maketrans("".join(used_punct),
    " "*len("".join(used_punct)))).split())


def remove_punct(val):
    test = list(val)
    for item in test:
        if item in d:
            test[test.index(item)] = ""
        elif item in string.punctuation:
            test[test.index(item)] = " " + item + " "
    return " ".join("".join(test).split())


def get_pos_dep(val):
    doc = nlp(remove_punct(" ".join(list(map(lambda x:x[0], val)))).lower())
    tokens = []
    for token in doc:
        tokens.append((token.text, token.pos_, token.dep_))
    ref_values = "".join(list(map(lambda x:(x[1]+",")*
                 len(remove_punct(x[0]).split()), val))).split(",")[:-1]
    final = []
    for item in list(zip(tokens, ref_values)):
        if item[0][1] != "PRON":
            item_ = tuple(list(item[0]) + [item[1]])
            final.append(item_)

    return [" ".join(list(map(lambda x:x[0], final))), " ".join(list(map(lambda x:x[1], final))), 
            " ".join(list(map(lambda x:x[2], final))), ",".join(list(map(lambda x:x[3], final)))]
```

Answer (score 2):

What about using asynchronous approach e.g. Quart? It is very same to Flask but asynchronous plus change gunicorn by hypercorn.

Quart:

> Quart is a Python ASGI web
>   microframework. It is intended to provide the easiest way to use
>   asyncio functionality in a web context, especially with existing Flask
>   apps. This is possible as the Quart API is a superset of the Flask API. https://gitlab.com/pgjones/quart

Hypercorn:

> Hypercorn is an ASGI web server based on the sans-io hyper, h11, h2, and wsproto libraries and inspired by Gunicorn. Hypercorn supports HTTP/1, HTTP/2, and websockets and the ASGI 2 specification. Hypercorn can utilise asyncio, uvloop, or trio worker types. https://pgjones.gitlab.io/hypercorn/